# Extracting common attributes from a Dark and Light theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I have a dark theme and a light theme in my app where the dark theme extends Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar and the light theme extends Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.

I have a lot of custom attributes in those light and dark theme that i have to duplicate in both those themes.

I was wondering if there is a way to actually have all those attributes in a common place and be used by both light and dark theme.

Example below to make things even more clear:

```
 <style name="MotherThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Base application theme common to all sdk versions -->
        <!--Colors-->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/brand_dark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/brand</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/brand_accent</item>
        <item name="colorPositive">@color/positive</item>
        <item name="colorPositiveDark">@color/positive_dark</item>
        <item name="colorNegative">@color/negative</item>
        <item name="colorNegativeDark">@color/negative_dark</item>
        <item name="colorNegativeLight">@color/negative_light</item>
        <item name="colorMedium">@color/medium</item>
....
...Things specific to this theme goes here
....
</style>



 <style name="MotherTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <!-- Base application theme common to all sdk versions -->
            <!--Colors-->
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/brand_dark</item>
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/brand</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/brand_accent</item>
            <item name="colorPositive">@color/positive</item>
            <item name="colorPositiveDark">@color/positive_dark</item>
            <item name="colorNegative">@color/negative</item>
            <item name="colorNegativeDark">@color/negative_dark</item>
            <item name="colorNegativeLight">@color/negative_light</item>
            <item name="colorMedium">@color/medium</item>
    ....
    ...Things specific to this theme goes here
    ....
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways is to put the common attributes in a theme overlay (assuming you are using the AppCompat library), e.g. -

```
<style name=“MyCustomOverlay” parent=”ThemeOverlay.AppCompat”>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/brand_dark</item>
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/brand</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/brand_accent</item>
   <item name="colorPositive">@color/positive</item>
   <item name="colorPositiveDark">@color/positive_dark</item>
   <item name="colorNegative">@color/negative</item>
   <item name="colorNegativeDark">@color/negative_dark</item>
   <item name="colorNegativeLight">@color/negative_light</item>
   <item name="colorMedium">@color/medium</item>
</style>
```

and then apply `android:theme=”MyCustomOverlay”` to your root views. This will override the attributes set in your base theme (e.g. `MotherTheme` or `MotherThemeDark`) for the root views and all child views.  Works for API 11+.

Reference: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/JXHKyhsWHAH

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i used your answer to come up with a different solution since i was already applying the dark theme to root layout i then made the dark theme extend ThemeOverlay Dark and put all the dark specific attributes in there.

Comment: @headduck check out the answer that i posted to see how i actually did it.

Answer (score 0):

Although I made the above post as an answer, since it helped me find a solution i will post the actual solution here :

I made the dark theme extend ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark and then applied the motherThemeDark to the root layout of the fragment/activity that i wanted to be themed dark. Under the motherThemeDark i only had attributes that i wanted to override for a dark theme.

```
<style name="MotherTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <!-- Base application theme common to all sdk versions -->
            <!--Colors-->
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/brand_dark</item>
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/brand</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/brand_accent</item>
            <item name="colorPositive">@color/positive</item>
            <item name="colorPositiveDark">@color/positive_dark</item>
            <item name="colorNegative">@color/negative</item>
            <item name="colorNegativeDark">@color/negative_dark</item>
            <item name="colorNegativeLight">@color/negative_light</item>
            <item name="colorMedium">@color/medium</item>
            ....
            ...Things specific to this theme goes here
            ....
</style>



 <style name="MotherThemeDark" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    ....   
    ....
    ...Things specific to this theme goes here
    ....
 </style>
```